# SSRS Mail Configuration

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I use SSRS 2014 in a project. I created reports and i want send these reports with mail.
This is my mail configurations:

```
<Extension Name="Report Server Email" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider,ReportingServicesEmailDeliveryProvider">
                <MaxRetries>3</MaxRetries>
                <SecondsBeforeRetry>900</SecondsBeforeRetry>
                <Configuration>
                    <RSEmailDPConfiguration>
                        <SMTPServer>mail.???.com</SMTPServer>
                        <SMTPServerPort>???</SMTPServerPort>
                        <SMTPAccountName>
                        </SMTPAccountName>
                        <SMTPConnectionTimeout>
                        </SMTPConnectionTimeout>
                        <SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
                        </SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
                        <SMTPUseSSL>False</SMTPUseSSL>
                        <SendUsing>2</SendUsing>
                        <SMTPAuthenticate>1</SMTPAuthenticate>
                        <SendUserName>report@???.com</SendUserName>
                        <SendPassword>???</SendPassword>
                        <From>report@???.com</From>
                        <EmbeddedRenderFormats>
                            <RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension>
                        </EmbeddedRenderFormats>
                        <PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
                        </PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
                        <ExcludedRenderFormats>
                            <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
                            <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
                            <RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension>
                        </ExcludedRenderFormats>
                        <SendEmailToUserAlias>True</SendEmailToUserAlias>
                        <DefaultHostName>
                        </DefaultHostName>
                        <PermittedHosts>
                        </PermittedHosts>
                    </RSEmailDPConfiguration>
                </Configuration>
            </Extension>
```

I saw that message:

Failure sending mail: The mailbox is unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Authentication Required

I used that e mail configuration in other vb.net projects and it is successfully working. What is the problem in my codes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From our experience, you have to use an internal SMTP server, we couldn't get this working with an external SMTP server so we had to install IIS 6 on another server, configure it with the external SMTP server account details and use that as an email relay for the reports.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In that time, we didn't solve this problem. And now we use another solition. But if i use that product, i will try it.